# Can we please change the order of the pinned topics in our Help Center?

Tags: bug

I noticed that our [Help Center](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/help) has the pinned posts in a different order than I'm used to seeing on many of the [other](https://movies.stackexchange.com/help) [sites](https://english.stackexchange.com/help).

It seems that it may be a matter of site age what the default order for these pins is but the order on the other sites makes a lot more sense to me and I'd appreciate it if we could have the same order here on A&C.

Currently the order is:

- What types of questions should I avoid asking?
- What does it mean if a question is "closed" or "on hold"?
- What topics can I ask about here?

The order on the other sites, which I prefer, is:

- What topics can I ask about here?
- What types of questions should I avoid asking?
- What does it mean if a question is "closed" or "on hold"?

This is a much more natural progression. It sets the emphasis on the positive question "what **can** I ask about" - which is also something we can customize to the site - whereas the others are generic, less helpful, and more negative.

There's actually a general request for this on MSE but, since it's been passed over, I thought I'd ask it here.

Comment: Is this something we don't have control over then and need a mod to look at?

Comment: If I could do it, I would have. :(

Comment: Related: [Why is “what can I ask about here” not the first entry in the help center?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/263685/162011)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Short answer is "ask a CM."

Longer answer is that there is no tool specifically for choosing the order of these, it depends on what was pinned most recently, and also edited most recently, which is *sometimes* mod-editable depending on the page, but probably not for all pages, and yadda yadda yadda just ping one of us.

Bonus answer is that I seem to have uncovered a bug while looking into this (NO I DID NOT BREAK IT IT WAS ALREADY BROKEN STOP LOOKING AT ME LIKE THAT) so it'll be just a moment to actually re-order these for you...